# Mi Yodea Series on numbers

Tags: discussion

Where can i find the series of Mi Yoda that goes through the significance of numbers?

(somewhere on this website, not sure how to locate the complete list)

Answer (score 5):

I was writing the answer until it got migrated :). Here you go!

You can find the posts, categorized by number, by looking at the "[mi-yodeya-series]"- tagged questions.

On [page 15](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series?tab=newest&page=25&pagesize=15), you'll find the numbers [1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/378/echad-mi-yodeya) through [12](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/696/shneim-asar-mi-yodeya).

[image]

It starts with the number (written) and with the word "- mi yodeya?" behind it.

To search, type in what you are looking for in the search-bar, and then end with the following: [mi-yodeya-series]. For example, if you are looking for all the numbers that have a 1 in them, do the following:

[image]

Comment: Maybe explain how to search for questions in a specific tag

Comment: I did, feel free to do it also yourself if you have other tricks/tips.

Comment: Here are some general search tips https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/searching